# useInfiniteSWR with axios and typescript

Tags: typescript, vercel, swr

We have a very good example on how to use useSWR hooks for axios and typescript on the official repo here https://github.com/vercel/swr/blob/master/examples/axios-typescript/libs/useRequest.ts

```
import useSWR, { SWRConfiguration, SWRResponse } from 'swr'
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse, AxiosError } from 'axios'

export type GetRequest = AxiosRequestConfig | null

interface Return<Data, Error>
  extends Pick<
    SWRResponse<AxiosResponse<Data>, AxiosError<Error>>,
    'isValidating' | 'revalidate' | 'error' | 'mutate'
  > {
  data: Data | undefined
  response: AxiosResponse<Data> | undefined
}

export interface Config<Data = unknown, Error = unknown>
  extends Omit<
    SWRConfiguration<AxiosResponse<Data>, AxiosError<Error>>,
    'initialData'
  > {
  initialData?: Data
}

export default function useRequest<Data = unknown, Error = unknown>(
  request: GetRequest,
  { initialData, ...config }: Config<Data, Error> = {}
): Return<Data, Error> {
  const { data: response, error, isValidating, revalidate, mutate } = useSWR<
    AxiosResponse<Data>,
    AxiosError<Error>
  >(
    request && JSON.stringify(request),
    /**
     * NOTE: Typescript thinks `request` can be `null` here, but the fetcher
     * function is actually only called by `useSWR` when it isn't.
     */
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
    () => axios(request!),
    {
      ...config,
      initialData: initialData && {
        status: 200,
        statusText: 'InitialData',
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
        config: request!,
        headers: {},
        data: initialData
      }
    }
  )

  return {
    data: response && response.data,
    response,
    error,
    isValidating,
    revalidate,
    mutate
  }
}
```

How to implement the example on using  useSWRInfinite with axios and typescript?

Comment: What have you tried, and what specific issue are you facing?

Comment: i try to replicate this example provided by swr repo but using useSWRInfinite

Answer (score 0):

Maybe old but with latest update, it will give you something like this now :

```
import { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse, AxiosError } from "axios";

import axios from "./request";

import useSWRInfinite, {
  SWRInfiniteConfiguration,
  SWRInfiniteResponse,
} from "swr/infinite";

export type GetRequest = AxiosRequestConfig | null;

interface InfiniteReturn<Data, Error>
  extends Pick<
    SWRInfiniteResponse<AxiosResponse<Data>, AxiosError<Error>>,
    "isValidating" | "error" | "mutate" | "size" | "setSize"
  > {
  data: Data[] | undefined;
  response: AxiosResponse<Data>[] | undefined;
}

export interface InfiniteConfig<Data = unknown, Error = unknown>
  extends Omit<
    SWRInfiniteConfiguration<AxiosResponse<Data>, AxiosError<Error>>,
    "fallbackData"
  > {
  fallbackData?: Data[];
}

export default function useRequestInfinite<Data = unknown, Error = unknown>(
  getRequest: (index: number, previousPageData: AxiosResponse<Data> | null) => GetRequest,
  { fallbackData, ...config }: InfiniteConfig<Data, Error> = {},
): InfiniteReturn<Data, Error> {
  const { data: response, error, isValidating, mutate, size, setSize } = useSWRInfinite<
    AxiosResponse<Data>,
    AxiosError<Error>
  >(
    (index, previousPageData) => {
      const key = getRequest(index, previousPageData);
      return key ? JSON.stringify(key) : null;
    },
    request => client(JSON.parse(request)),
    {
      ...config,
      fallbackData:
        fallbackData &&
        fallbackData.map(i => ({
          status: 200,
          statusText: "InitialData",
          config: {},
          headers: {},
          data: i,
        })),
    },
  );

  return {
    data: response && response.map(r => r.data),
    response,
    mutate,
    error,
    isValidating,
    size,
    setSize,
  };
}
```